# How to parse the apache log files correctly in spark scala?

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am try to read apache log file and trying to put that into dataframe after parsing.

To start with I have taken a sample line of the log and did some exercise using regex to parse the same.However when I am trying to implement the same in the code it is saying "no match found" even though it works correctly in DEMO.Please help.

https://regex101.com/r/yS3lY3/2

```
package common

object loganalysis extends App {

  import common._
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
  import java.util.regex.Pattern
  import java.util.regex.Matcher
  import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

  val spSession = SparkCommonUtils.spSession
  val spContext = SparkCommonUtils.spContext

  import spSession.implicits._

  val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(spContext)

  val regex = """(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})? (\S+) (\S+) (\[.+?\]) \"(.*?)\" (\d{3}) (\S+) \"(.*?)\" \"(.*?)\""""

  val p = Pattern.compile(regex)

  val logLine = s"""94.102.63.11 - - [21/Jul/2009:02:48:13 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 18209 "http://acme.com/foo.php" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)""""

  val matcher = p.matcher(logLine)

  println(matcher.group(1))

  }
```

At present it says no match found and errors out.I would like to see each of the parsed strings separately and finally I would like to generalise to apply it on the entire file so that it can handle the exceptions too when no match is found.

Comment: You have to run `matcher.matches` after `val matcher = p.matcher(logLine)`  For example https://ideone.com/Pj7Qfi

Comment: Thanks @Thefourthbird .Got it.I am now trying to generalise it on dataframe with single column which is this complete string.I would like to split that into multiple columns to do my further analysis.

Comment: I read the file using ```val logFile = sqlContext.read.text("file:///C:/Users/xxx/Downloads/logs//test.log") val split_df = logFile.withColumn("host", regexp_extract(logFile("value"), raw"^([^\s]+\s)", 1)) ``` But I want to apply the regex in the question on complete dataframe and get multiple columns out of it.If somewhere pattern is not matching,0 should come.I am new to scala.Can someone please help?